# Simulator get blanked when running app in debug mode second time in 14.1 and 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I just upgraded both of my Macbook Pro M2 to MacOS Ventura 13.0 and Xcode to Version 14.1 (14B47b)

After updating my xcode, my xcode is always stuck on "launching app" and simulator is on blackscreen every 2nd time I run the code.

Steps to duplicate.

1. Close the simulator
2. Build and run code
3. Here, xcode runs the code perfectly.
4. After I made changes in code and re-run the code, Xcode is now stuck on "launching app" and simulator is on blackscreen
5. To run the code again, I would have to go back to step 1 again to run the app on simulator.

Does anyone have an idea on how can I fix this.

I tried removing derived data, changing simulators but didn't fixed the issue.

UPD:
I know this is not a solution, but just paste this command to restart simulator automatically. Add Run Script at Build Phase section and enter command "killall Simulator":
:
[Run Script command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxjqB.png)

We will wait fix this problem from Apple in a new version, but for now you could manually restart Simulator or make it automatically through Run Script.

And also I noticed that without restart app runs with black background and you can even swipe to Home Screen.

Comment: Please file a bug with Apple.

Comment: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: I am also facing same problem with m1 chip

Comment: I was facing this issue by way of temporary solutions likes

1./ a scheme's "Build Pre-actions"
2./ killall "Simulator" || true

Comment: Please find the possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665691/8751294

Answer (score 8):

This is bug with the latest version. you need to quit the simulator and run the project again. You can always file a bug with apple as @matt commented.

Comment: This absolutely worked for me with Xcode 14.1, and I encourage everyone to submit a bug report to apple.

Answer (score 3):

Update:
I Have downloaded version 14.2 (14C18) and the problem seems to be fixed

Original answer:
I have the same problem. The only solution I have found so far is that if the app crashes it works fine the next time.
So i added a button to force crash the app in order to save me time for restarting the emulator.
I know this is not a solution but this allows me to continue development until apple fix the problem

Comment: I have updated Xcode 14.2, but sometimes it is still tucked when running the app

Comment: No it still happens in XCode 14.2 for me on mac mini M1

Answer (score 1):

The same problem I faced, close the simulator once you run the build without stopping running the code.

Comment: I have updated Xcode 14.2, but sometimes it is still tucked when running the app

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here: After first run of an app using XCode debug the simulator is just black. Killing the app does not help.

Debugging/running the simulator with XCode 14.1 was fine until I updated to Ventura, the problem started with the OS upgrade.

This did **not** work for me:

```
sudo xcrun simctl erase all
```

Manually resetting the simulator also did not work.

Only thing that helps at the moment is closing the simulator and starting it again.

Comment: have you tried crashing the app before run it again ?

Comment: I think it might be really the issue with Ventura. Because on Monterey it worked fine for me. Now I regret upgrading to Ventura

Comment: I too have the same problem, only solution that works is to restart the simulator every time and that pains!

Answer (score -4):

I am using xcode 14.1 What I have done is as follows:

Quit the simulator & Xcode.
Open terminal and run

> sudo xcrun simctl erase all

It will delete all content of all simulators. By content if you logged in somewhere password will be gone, all developer apps installed in that simulator will be gone.

**Doing these resolved my issue. Hope it helps.**

Comment: Did not work for me. 
"sudo xcrun simctl erase all" actually did not reset my simulator.

Comment: Don't say sudo.

Comment: sometime it worked for me sometime not, its not the perfect solution