# Black screen my app on Simulator and stuck at Launching App every couple of runs - macos ventura

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15

While developing native apps from Xcode, the screen of my app goes black and Xcode is stuck on launching app and attaching to iPhone 14 Pro as in screenshot below:

[image: xcode & simulator]

When my app's screen goes black, the simulator still works normally. If I kill my app and restart it, it stuck on launch screen.

I tried before last updates to set to Rosetta Stone, but I was facing same issue. After updating Xcode and macOS, I don't even have the Rosetta option.

[image: xcode no rosetta option]

I am using:

- Device: **Macbook Pro, M1 Pro**
- Xcode: **14.3 (14E222b)**
- macOS: **Ventura 13.3.1**
- project is developed with Swift, uses Cocoapods

The only thing that works now is killing the process of the simulator completely, and restarting it from Xcode.

***NOTE***: When I develop *flutter* apps from Android studio on iOS Simulator, everything works just fine.

***UPDATE: 09/19/2023***:
It is still the same on Xcode 15.0 public release.

[image: black screen on iPhone15 xcode 15.0]

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74315983/simulator-get-blanked-when-running-app-in-debug-mode-second-time-in-14-1-and-14 probably

Comment: I too have the exact same problem, no luck so far except restarting the simulator every time !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 14 stuck at Launching App on Simulator after few runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871974/xcode-14-stuck-at-launching-app-on-simulator-after-few-runs)

Comment: Well, today I tried Xcode 15 and I'm not facing the black/unresponsive screen anymore and I didn't change any setting. At least, my case seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have added `Excluded Architectures - arm64` for `Any iOS Simulator SDK`, please remove that for all targets in your app.

[image]

Also, if you are using `Pods` and have implemented this code on your `Podfile`,

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

please **delete** this from `Podfile` and hit `pod install`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will cause my program to fail to compile under the emulator

Comment: @Rakuyo Please amake sure you have removed `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` from all targest included the pods. Also this does not work (the app won't run in simulator) if you are using Xcode with Rosetta.

Comment: If we remove those settings, the build will fail if running the app in a machine with Apple Silicon, right? I remember adding those settings to be able to debug the app in my MacBook Pro with M1

Comment: @ricardopereira Yes, it was required on the older versions of Xcodes, but now (I have tested it from Xcode 14.2) if you remove these and you don't have any framework/library that is built with these requirements, it will work, and solve the issue with the stuck-on black screen on the simulator.

Comment: Well, today I tried Xcode 15 and I'm not facing the black/unresponsive screen anymore and I didn't change any setting. At least, my case seems to be fixed.

Comment: This solution solved the exact topicstarter problem for me in Xcode 15. Though, I had to do a whole bunch of version updates for used pods.

Answer (score -3):

i have same issue, and i will done to this.
move all your project to local drive (i dont know but when i move to local this work). Dont put your project to icloud.